# Powershell handle exception System.Management.Automation.RemoteException

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

I am building a basic `powershell script` here. What i want to do is run this `aws command` in `powershell`
`aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::xx" --role-session-name xx` and if there is an error response which is `An error occurred (ExpiredToken) when calling the AssumeRole operation: The security token included in the request is expired` I want to display to user `refresh your token`. If the `aws command` is successful it returns a `response` with `key value` which are separated by `=`. I am new to `powershell`. Below is my `powershell`

```
$output = aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::xx" --role-session-name xx 2>&1 | %{ "$_" }

if ($output.Contains("error")) {
   Write-Host "Refresh your token"
}
else {
   Write-Host "read the aws key details and update aws .configure here " + $output
}

Write-Host "Done"
```

In the `$output` i am getting the below response `System.Management.Automation.RemoteException An error occurred (ExpiredToken) when calling the AssumeRole operation: The security token included in the request is expired Done`
The `if` condtion which has `Contains("error")` is not working.

I am using `Powershell version 5.1.19041.1682`

Comment: `(aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::xx" --role-session-name xx 2>&1).Contains("error")` give you the same result?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala yes it does the same thing..does not return true even though these is an `"error"` string in the `response`

Comment: What is the type of `$output`? `$output.gettype()`

Comment: @Otter thanks..its an array so ofcourse Contains would not work..i can loop through the array and check for the presence of `error` string in one of the item of the array and it works..thanks guys for your help